# Assigning a value to a constant syntax or semantic error?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, syntax-error, lvalue

Is the second line of code considered as a syntax error or a semantic error in C++?

```
 int a = 7;
 3 = a;
```

In standard C++ context-free grammar I found this statement syntactically valid.

Comment: it's a semantic error.

Comment: It's a conceptual error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a syntax error, as the grammar can derive from *assignment-expression* (5.17) up to *integer_literal*

It is then a semantic error, as stated in 5.17:

> All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an
>   lvalue referring to the left operand.

*lvalue* is a semantic concept, not a syntactic one.